# Highcharts x axis dates displayed slanting

Tags: highcharts, axis-labels

Im using Highcharts to generate a line chart. On my x-axis, I use dates and its all displaying but for some reason its displaying slanting.

How can I fix it? Here is my x-axis properties.

```
xAxis: {
    categories: report_2_weekly_categories,
    tickInterval: 180,
    labels:{
        format : '{value} CST'
    }
},
```

[image]

Comment: Because they're clearly too wide to fit horizontally. Check the docs for relevant properties to fix: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.rotation | http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.autoRotation

Comment: What would you like the behavior to be?  There are lots of options, you can wrap, you can stagger, you can show only every nth label, or you can rotate. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels

Comment: If you have dates on your xAxis, why you don't want to use datetime type of your axis?